# Instaling linux-oem-20.04b kernel in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, kernel, dell

**The problem:**
Intel audio hardware used in the Dell XPS 17 is not supported by kernel 5.11 in 21.04.

**Solution:**
Canonical has solved the problem for the LTS release & I have found a way [to install the linux-oem-20.04b kernel in 21.04](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/DELL-XPS-17-9700-Ubuntu-Debian-Linux/td-p/7861072).

**The question:**

- Before I do this, I would like to better understand the danger and the possible consequences.
- Is a simple "sudo apt remove..." enough to revere the changes in case something goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: to remove a kernel you need to boot into another one like your current one then yes sudo apt autoremove linux-image-5.10.0-1023-oem (or very close to that) will remove the OEM kernel.

Second familiarize yourself with grub changes or use grub-customizer because you may not get a menu entry for the OEM kernel.

Third 21.04 will complain about outdated binaries when running this older kernel. I ignore them as its at least working for me. In my case mg onboard graphics only work right with the OEM kernel.